# Tool that detects duplicate javascript function names in a web page?

Tags: javascript

**Background**

We have a web application in which several developers have written several .js files that manipulate the DOM and the problem of duplicate function names has crept into our application.

**Question**

Can anyone recommend a tool that will warn us when we accidentally write a web page with two javascript functions with the same name?

**Example**

*HTML page*

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>function foo() {alert('bar');}</script>
```

*test.js*

```
function foo() {alert('foo');}
```

Since foo() is declared twice in the page, apparently only the one that takes precedence is loaded.

The tools I've used seem to ignore this. Firebug only shows the loaded function. Netbeans will show both functions in navigator (without a warning), but only looks at one file at a time (ie, I can't point it at the HTML file and see it and the .js at the same time.) and web developer extensions allows me to look at everything at once, but no errors or warnings. Firefox's error console also throws no warning or error. Neither does IE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, using a parser may not always be ideal as it requires an extra step of copying and pasting your code, and everyone else's, into the parser and even then I'm not sure it would catch what you want. The time tested solution to collaborative Javascript development is to namespace your code.

```
var myNamespace = function (){
   var myPrivateProperty;
   var myPrivateFunction = function(){};
   return{

      myPublicProperty: '',
      myPublicFunction: function(){}


   }

 }();
```

This is based on Douglas Crockford's [module pattern](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/).

Then you can call your public functions this way:

```
 myNamespace.myPublicFunction();
```

And your public properties:

```
 myNamespace.myPublicProperty;
```

Each developer can develop in their own namespace so as to not step on others' code.

Comment: Since it's clear that there's not an ideal tool that'll work for our specific situation, I brought this idea to my boss - he had me throw together a PoC and it looks like we're going to be using it going forward. We might even try to implement it on existing code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have often used [JSLINT](http://jslint.com/)

In short it is a "compiler" for JavaScript using JavaScript.  I have learned a lot by watching Douglas Crockford’s training videos.

It not only checks for duplicate functions, but global variables, and a whole bunch of other things.  Like Douglas said in one of his videos it allows you to only use the good bits of JavaScript

Comment: +1 for jslint. Especially good for catching unusual browser-dependent problems

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did try jsLint, and found it useful, but because I'm dealing with multiple JS files as well as scripting in the HTML pages themselves, it was hard to work with. The ideal tool I'm looking for would take a URL or HTML file as input, and return all the problems.

Comment: Steve do you use visual studio?  I found a really funky tool, that does JSLINT as part of your build process?

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be a simple HTML parser for Java (I just hacked one with regexps; you may want to try http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers/jtidy) and the Apache Rhino library (http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/doc.html).

It should be possible to overload the parser in Rhino to throw an error if a function is redefined.

I'm using a slightly modified version of env.js (http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery/build/runtest/env.js) by John Resig to emulate a browser. This allows me to test JavaScript in JUnit tests. I can fill in forms, submit them, check the layout of the pages, etc.

See my blog for details: http://blog.pdark.de/2008/11/18/testing-the-impossible-javascript-in-a-web-page/

Comment: the weblog links is dead

Answer (score 1):

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Me, Page.GetType, "jsTest", "test.js")